# CustomLoginPage Sample

Tags: identityserver3

I am trying to run the CustomLoginPage sample, but I am getting an error in CustomLoginPageUserService class with the PreAuthenticateAsync method. Following line is returning null:
var id = ctx.Request.Query.Get("signin");

Is there any thing I need to add in the url to generate a the signin cookie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The client MUST be in the same project as the IS3 server. It took me forever to find that answer. I fell victim to the same lack of documentation in the example....